# How to add meta data in invoice object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

How to add metadata in invoice object of Stripe while subscription creation?
If we look into the [subscription object details](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object), it has **`metadata`** field, but it does not belong to the ***invoice object***.
The reason behind the requirement is, I need to catch the failed payments through **`invoice.payment_failed`** webhook. Is there any way I could achieve this? 
All kind of suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Invoices have a [metadata property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-metadata).

If you are generating invoices manually, you can set the `metadata` value when creating the invoice.

For automatically generated invoices, such as those created at the start/end of a subscription's billing period, you can watch for the `invoice.created` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created) and then [update the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update) with the desired metadata.

Comment: I need to add those metadata at the time of subscription creation. If decide to add metadata through the webhook, I will lose the program execution scope

Comment: Since invoices aren't created until a payment is due, your best bet is going to be to use the subscription's metadata property and then use the value there to update each invoice with that same metadata. There currently isn't any way to set a default value for invoice metadata.